# Where can I get alerts for future delisting of stocks/ETFs?

Tags: equities, programming, etf, european, american

I scan / trade a universe of 1500 different European and US stocks and ETFs trading on many different exchanges.

I would like to get notified before any of the tickers are delisted, so I can sell any holdings of a stock or ETF before delisted.

Does anyone know of a - free or paid - website or API (preferably) where I can get about delistings *before* they happen (effective date)?

Comment: Official websites of the Exchanges have this info:https://www.nyse.com/regulation/delistings or https://www.euronext.com/en/exchange-publications/cash/notices

Comment: Thank you, @AK88. Appreciate you taking time to answer/specify the links. A way to get the info for all tickers in one place/API would be preferred as the 1500 tickers are traded on around 25 different exchanges, so I'll see if somebody has an input for that.